# Call external site webmethod using jsonp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, jsonp

I'm trying to call external site webmethod, and post some data. I tried a lot of different ways and still cannot get the method to be called.

Here is my js code:

```
$.ajax({
            url: "http://sitename.com/methods.aspx/mywebmethod",
            data: "{'id':'" + 4 + "'}",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

Here is my webmethod code:

```
[WebMethod()]
        public static bool mywebmethod(int id)
        {
if(id != 0){
            return true;}
else{return false;}
        }
```

and I always get the same response

```
Error: jQuery{code} was not called
```

**What I'm missing?**

Answer (score 3):

JSONP is not magic.

You can only use JSONP to read data from a URL that returns [JSONP script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).
ASP.Net WebMethods do not support JSONP.

Comment: You can't. You need to understand how JSONP works.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP

Comment: Yes, use a server side script to call the external webservice. Forget about javascript. And to understand why you should forget about javascript, follow SLaks advice and read about JSONP to understand how it works and also read about the same origin policy restriction that's built into browsers and which prevents you from sending cross domain AJAX requests.

Comment: in my case I need to make a call from client side

Comment: In this case you will have to modify the remote service so that it returns JSONP instead of JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're missing the proper attributes, as following (in an .asmx definition):

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)] // optional, but usually forgotten
    [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public bool MyMethod(int id)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

plus, you need to have Content-rewrite module for handling the leading callback parameter as well:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43038/Accessing-Remote-ASP-NET-Web-Services-Using-JSONP