# jsonp syntax error unexpected token

Tags: jsonp

if I use dataType: `json` I don't get an error in the response/

If I use dataType: `jsonp` I get the following error:

> syntax error unexpected token

This is my jquery code

```
function testJsonp()
{
            $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "http://localhost/FT8Services/FTService.asmx/testjsonp",                                
                            data: "{firstname: '" + encodeURIComponent("Stack") + "', lastname: '" + encodeURIComponent("Overflow") + "'}",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "jsonp",                               
                            success: function (result) {                   
                                var loginfo = eval(result.d);
                                alert(loginfo[0]);
                                if(loginfo.length > 1)
                                {
                                    alert("Sucess");    
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert("no access");
                                }
                            },
                            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                                alert(error);
                            }       
                        })
}
```

and this is my asp.net web method

```
 <WebMethod()> _
Public Function testjsonp(ByVal firstname As String, ByVal lastname As String) As String
    Dim rdatas As New List(Of String)
    Dim fullname As String = firstname & lastname
    For i As Integer = 1 To 5
        rdatas.Add(fullname & " " & i.ToString)
    Next
    Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
    Dim strJSON As String = js.Serialize(rdatas.ToArray)

    Return strJSON
End Function
```

Comment: Do you know what jsonp is?

Comment: we using for cross domain acesss

Comment: That answers what it's used for, not what it "is".  What it "is" is a bit of javascript code that's loaded with a script tag; the code generally consists a single invocation of a function you (or jQuery, as it were, with your code) with the data passed in as a parameter.  What it "is" what what your code "isn't" might tell us what's wrong. I don't recall whether or not there's any way tagging a method as a `WebMethod` can give you the ability to use JSONP as a way to retrieve data or not. My guess would be it's not rendering the code as I've explained.

Comment: i answer you wat it's used for i didn't tell what it is

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't asking for my own learning, I was asking to see If you understood the basic concept, because so many people *don't*. I could have elaborated my question did a little better.

Comment: sorry i here to get advice from other programmers not to argue with you

Comment: Re-read the comments.  Does it look like I'm arguing with you?  I'm inquiring what you know as that relates to the question.  *That is not an argument.* Anyways there are many ways to support JSONP According to one of the answers on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9997310/call-external-site-webmethod-using-jsonp (which is essentially the same question as yours), `WebMethod` is not among them.

Comment: hi jayc can u tell me how to achive this "JSONP is not magic.

You can only use JSONP to read data from a URL that returns JSONP script."  because i tried like following but i am getting same error looks like my web service return xml instead of json <div id="container" >
 <script src="http://localhost/FT8Services/FTService.asmx/testjsonp?firstname=stack&lastname=overflow&jsonp=jsonSuccess"></script>
</div>